# What cases should I use dollar sign and single quotes in transliterate (eg. tr -d '\n'), or any other function?

Tags: bash, tr

Say Im trying to delete newlines or carrige returns. I notice that when I use transliterate to delete the newline characters `tr -d '\n'`, I get the same results as if I were to `tr -d $"\n"` or `tr -d $'\n'`. What's the difference?

I'm not sure how the same applies in sed or grep because they are more complicated. So, I'm trying to figure out tr first as that seems to be a simpler bash program.

Comment: Without the `$` it is `tr` that creates the newline character, with the `$` it is bash.  `tr` is *not* a "bash program", it has nothing to do with the shell, beyond commonly being executed from bash.

Comment: Would you call it a bash utility?

Comment: I would just call it a utility program.  I know its only semantics, but these programs can be called from any language, they are not tied to bash.  Of course they are designed to be called from a shell, so "shell utility program" would be not so bad.  Most of these programs (the original versions anyway) pre-date bash by about 20 years.  It is important to realise they are separate programs, and have all the overhead of running in a separate process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`tr` does its own escaping:

- When you write `tr -d '\n'`, the `tr` program itself recognises `\`+`n` and substitutes a newline.
- When you write `tr -d $'\n'`, Bash converts `\n` to a newline character, and tr sees it literally.

If you're experimenting to understand what the shell does, it's probably worth writing a short C program to print out each argument letter by letter - something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i;

    /* Ignore argv[0] - the program name is not interesting */
    for (i = 1;  i < argc;  ++i) {
        char *p = argv[i];
        printf("argv[%d] =", i);
        while (*p)
            printf(" %3d", (int)*p++);
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This one prints in decimal, but it's easy to change it to use hex or octal.  Running it with `$'\n'` `\n` `"\n"` as arguments gives:

```
argv[1] =  10
argv[2] = 110
argv[3] =  92 110
```

showing that in the first case, Bash passes a single newline character, in the second case, just the 'n', and in the final case, both '\' and 'n'.

Comment: You don't need C to see this. Just `set -x` and `printf`: `set -x; printf %q\\n \n '\n' $'\n'`. Or to get more similar output to your example: `printf %d\\n \'\n \''\n' \'$'\n'`. Though that second one only shows the code for the slash in the second case.

Comment: Wow, I did not know tr did its own escapes

Comment: Is tr a unique exception, or do other bash tools also do this?

Comment: It's not quite unique - for example, `sed` interprets some escape sequences in the substitution part of its `s` command (whether that is read from a file or from program arguments).  BTW, a note on terminology - sed and tr and other commands aren't "bash tools" - they are ordinary commands, and can be used from any shell (not just Bash).

Comment: @Etan - you're right, but for didactic purposes, I believe that writing one's own program is a clearer way to explore what happens both sides of the `exec()` syscall.